# Unterschied zwischen "anhören" und "sich anhören"?

Tags: difference, reflexive

Es gibt hier schon Fragen nach "hören" und "anhören", aber was ich verstehe nicht ist ob "anhören" immer mit "sich" benutzt wird?

In Duden, zwei Beispiele für anhören sind:

> ein Konzert, eine Debatte, eine Rede anhören
>
> heute Abend höre ich mir [im Radio] ein Hörspiel an

Dann, welche soll ich sagen: "Ich hörte eine Rede an." oder "Ich hörte **mir** eine Rede an."?

Comment: Der Unterschied ist subtil. Nach meinem Gefühl hat "Ich höre mir ein Lied an" mehr den Beiklang von Genuss und Entspannung. "Ich höre ein Lied an" könnte auch Arbeit sein.

Comment: @Nick - wahrscheinlich, weil ein Satz mit "ich ... mir" mitklingen lässt, dass ich etwas für mich (selber) tue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wenn ich *mir* etwas *anhöre*, dann mache ich das absichtlich und mit voller Aufmerksamkeit.
Beispiel: *"Ich **höre mir** die Nachrichten im Radio **an**. Sei bitte still."*

Wenn ich etwas *anhöre*, dann könnte das auch unbeabsichtigt, oder im Hintergrund sein.
Beispiel: *"Ich **höre** die Charts im Radio nur dann **an**, wenn ich arbeite."*
Siehe auch: [mit anhören](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anhoeren#Bedeutung-2)

Soweit ich weiss ist dies aber keine engültige Regel! Diese Sätze können auch vertauscht werden und Niemand wird sich beschweren.

---

**PS**: Es gibt noch [eine weitere Bedeutung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/anhoeren#Bedeutung-4) für "Sich anhören". Wenn durch ein Geräusch ein Eindruck vermittelt wird, dann "hört es sich an" nach etwas. Hier ist die Reflexive Verwendung notwendig.
Beispiel: "Du hörst dich an, als wärst du gerade eben aufgewacht."

Noch eine weitere Bedeutung von "anhören": Abstammend von der "[Anhörung](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/Anhoerung)", kann "anhören" auch "befragen" bedeuten in einem Gerichtlichen Kontext. Hier ist die reflexive Verwendung nicht möglich.
Auf diese Bedeutung bezieht sich die Antwort von @user41324

Comment: "nach etwas anhören" hat auf jeden Fall noch eine ganz eigene Bedeutung.

Comment: @Nick Das sagt er doch.

Answer (score 3):

"Anhören" kann reflexiv ("ich höre mir etwas an") und nicht-reflexiv ("ich höre jemanden an") sein.

Auch nach längerem Überlegen fällt mir für die nicht-reflexive Verwendung nur die Verwaltungs-/Justizsprache ein:
- Gerichte müssen Kinder anhören zu Sorgerechtsfragen
- Verwaltungen hören Verbände/Anlieger/Betroffene zu Planungen an

Als Faustregel kann wohl sagen: immer reflexiv ("ich höre mir etwas an") -- Ausnahme: sobald ein Amt/Gericht/Polizei in's Spiel kommt ("sie hören jemanden an"), ist es nicht-reflexiv.